# Hot water shut off valve

Tags: plumbing

While trying to turn off the hot water valve, the knob broke off in my hand. I have tried to grip it with channel locks but I cant grab it.

Comment: There are several different types of shutoff valves. A picture would help us figure it out.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. As @manassehkatz said, adding a picture to your question would really help us help you.

Comment: Some types have a replaceable "stem", the part that the handle is attached to, some do not and you must replace the entire valve. That's why a photo would help. Even if it is the type that is replaceable, you need to find the right replacement. If it is relatively new you may find it at a local hardware store, if it's old, maybe not.